# What's the difference between a Minhag and a takkanah

Tags: halacha, torah-study, rambam

What is the difference between a Minhag and Takkanah?

I know for example Rav Gershoms takkanah that a man is not allowed to divorce a woman against her own will is a Takkanah what's the difference between that and a Minhag?

Comment: takkanah by definition is imposed. Minhag is more organic

Comment: claiming this is similar to the other question implies that a minhag and a gezera are the same and they are. not